# Copy a database from old WAMP installation folder to another

Tags: mysql, wamp

I just install a fresh copy of WAMP, and I want to import couple of databases from the old one to the new one, so I entered to the old mysql data directory `C:\wamp-old\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\data`, and copy the relevant databases there to the new data directory. But when I try to access the tables in `phpmyadmin`, I get a message saying that the tables aren't exists, but they do:
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You forgot to copy the ibdata file. [image]

Comment: also copy ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1

Comment: Just copied the "data" folder from the old to the new install and worked :)

Comment: That's also a great alternative

Comment: This 100% worked for me and saved me hours of wasted time after a complete laptop meltdown.

Wamp / MySQL 5.7.19  to Wamp / MySQL 5.7.26

Comment: My wamp is ok, but the database cannot load. Shows the same error as the question author had.

Answer (score 7):

I did it successfully just now:

1. make a copy of wamp folder (wamp-old)
2. uninstall the wamp
3. install the new wamp (overwrite all the files if u were asked)
4. start the wamp
5. ck the localhost and phpmyadmin
6. copy your databases from the old-wamp only from C:\wamp-old\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\data and paste to the same location in new wamp
7. then copy and paste ibdata file from the above path and replace in new one.

You are done!

Answer (score 1):

you can not restore databases like this way,

Please follow this steps to restore the databases from old to one,

1. Backup all the databases using phpmyadmin (Export Feature)
2. Install the fresh XAMPP
3. Restore the all the databases using phpmyadmin (Import Feature)

Comment: What if I already install the new WAMP? My old wamp is under "wamp-copy"

Comment: Then replace all the files with old and reopen it,

Answer (score 1):

In my case the mySQL version of my old Wamp installation (5.7.26) was very different from the one in my new Wamp installation (8.0.21), so nothing from the solutions here worked for me.
I downloaded the old version of mysql from https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/#mysql_versions , installed it and replaced the hole ‘data’ folder with my old one.
Now from Wamp\MySQL\Version menu I can choose the old version and all my old databases are working fine.
You can leave that working version of mySQL or export the databases and import them to the new mySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

- Stop the wamp server
- Copy the entire data folder from the old WAMP to the new WAMP directory

**for MariaDB**

- **old directory:** C:\wamp64_old\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.4.10\data
- **new directory:** C:\wamp64\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.4.10\data

**For MySql**

- **old directory:** C:\wamp64_old\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.18\data
- **new directory:** C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.18\data

3. start the WAMP server again.

Answer (score -1):

Stop the Service (because it will complain for a file opened by another app) then Just copy and paste the ENTIRE (...\data) file from old installation folder backup to the new installation by overwirting the existing new installation file.

Finally, start the service.